# Find which button caused the segue action?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, segue

I'm new to iOS and struggling with this requirement.

I have a view with two readonly UITextField and two buttons. The textfields will hold start and end locations. Clicking either button segue's to a view with a TableView list of locations. Basically the user will click a button which takes them to the table view.... They choose the location they want and click done which segue's them back to the original view and will insert the chosen location into the textfield next to the button they originally click... This way I can use the same view for choosing both start and end locations.... with of course some logic so that they don't choose the same location for both. Eg from Home to Home.

If have this code...

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "segueChoiceMade") {
        let passingData = segue.destinationViewController as! LocationChoiceViewController;

        passingData.mileageToPass = mileageToPass
        passingData.fuelAmountToPass = fuelAmountToPass
        passingData.senderToPass = sender.identifier
    }
}
```

I was hoping that sender.identifier would have the button's identity but all I get is 'Some' ....

Is this how I should go about it? How do i get the button's identity? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sender` parameter is what you are looking for.
If you set the segue in Storyboard in sender you will always find  the object that has caused the segue.
Now with a simple if you can detect which button has triggered the segue.

```
   @IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if (segue.identifier == "segueChoiceMade") {
            let passingData = segue.destinationViewController as! LocationChoiceViewController
            if sender === myButton {
```

Since sender is an object you can check it against a reference to one of your object using the identity `===` operator. Or you can try to cast it using the `as?` operator to object you think it should be and check some of its internal properties